# Value of progress bar is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, indexeddb

I am trying to make a 'progress bar' using js and jquery by dividing "pages readed / total pages"  but the result of value 'perc' can't showing on progress bar, mayber there is somthing wrong in the function.
notice: in my code i used 'indexeddb' to store my database, also inside function of calculate i tried to get 'pages readead' value and 'total pages' by calling the values from the database like pageR = pages readed, pageE = page total.
In the code also I added a comment which element i want to assign to it 'perc' value to it to make it more clean.

[image]
here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        function calculate() {
        var perc = "";
        if (isNaN(pagesE.value) || isNaN(pagesR.value)) {
          perc = " ";
          updateProgressBar(myProgressBar, 0);
        } else {
          perc = ((pagesR.value / pagesE.value) * 100).toFixed(0);
          updateProgressBar(myProgressBar, perc)


        }
        document.getElementById('#progress__text').innerHTML = perc;
    }
    
    
    
    //Open Database
    var request = indexedDB.open('bookmanager',1);
    
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e){
        var db = e.target.result;
        


        if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('customers')){
            var os = db.createObjectStore('customers',{keyPath: "id", autoIncrement:true});
            //Create Index for Name
            os.createIndex('title','title',{unique:false});
        }
    }
    
    //Success
    request.onsuccess = function(e){
        console.log('Database working Success');
        db = e.target.result;
        //Show Customers
        showCustomers();
    }
    
    //Error
    request.onerror = function(e){
        console.log('Error: Opening Database!');
    }
});




//Add Customer
function addCustomer(){
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var author = $('#authorInput').val();
    var published = $('#publishedYear').val();
    var pagesR = $('#pagesRead').val();
    var pagesE = $('#allPages').val();
    var startD = $('#startDate').val();
    var endD = $('#endDate').val();
    var img = $('#img').val();



    var transaction = db.transaction(["customers"],"readwrite");
    //Ask for ObjectStore
    var store = transaction.objectStore("customers");
    
    //Define Customer
    var customer = {
        title: title,
        author: author,
        published: published,
        pagesR: pagesR,
        pagesE: pagesE,
        startD: startD,
        endD: endD,
        img: img
    }

    

    
    //Perform the Add
    var request = store.add(customer);
    
    //Success
    request.onsuccess = function(e){
        window.location.href="/index.html";
    }
    
    //Error
    request.onerror = function(e){
        alert("Sorry, the customer was not added");
        console.log('Error', e.target.error.title);
    }

}

function updateProgressBar(progressBar, value) {
    value = Math.round(value);
    progressBar.querySelector(".progress__fill").style.width = `${value}%`;
    progressBar.querySelector(".progress__text").textContent = `${value}%`;
  }
  
  const myProgressBar = document.querySelector(".progress");
  
  updateProgressBar(myProgressBar, 10);

//Display Customer
function showCustomers(e){
    var transaction = db.transaction(["customers"],"readonly");
    //Ask for ObjectStore
    var store = transaction.objectStore("customers");
    var index = store.index('title');

    
    
    var output = '';
    index.openCursor().onsuccess = function(e){


        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if(cursor){

            output += "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light'>";


            
            output += "<div class='progress'>";
            output += "<div class='progress__fill'></div>";
            //on the element bellow i want to assign perc value
            output += "<p class='progress__text'>1</p>";
            output += "</div>";

            output += "<img src='"+cursor.value.img+"' width='100px' height='120px'>";
            output += "<h3>"+cursor.value.title+"</h3>";
            output += "<a href='#' class='book-author'>"+cursor.value.author+"</a>";
            output += "<br>"
            output += "<a href='#' class='published'>"+cursor.value.published+"</a>";
            //output += "<p class='pages pagesS'>"+cursor.value.pagesR+"</p>"; 
            //output += "<p class='pages pagesE'>"+cursor.value.pagesE+"</p>";
            output += "<br>";
            output += "<p class='pages'>"+cursor.value.pagesR+" / "+cursor.value.pagesE+"</p>";
            output += "<br>";
            output += "<p class='date'>"+cursor.value.startD+" - "+cursor.value.endD+"</p>";

            //output += "<p class='date dateS'>"+cursor.value.startD+"</p>";
            //output += "<p class='date dateE'>"+cursor.value.endD+"</p>";
            output += "<button class='button-first'>Редактировать</button>";
            output +=  "<button class='button-second'>Удалить</button>";
            output += "</li>";

            cursor.continue();
        }
        //$('#customers').html(output);
        $('.list-group').html(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code under `<! HTML code -->` is JavaScript. Please show all the HTML accessed or updated by the jQuery code, as HTML, in the question itself. Preferably combine all the code into a code snippet (see under [How to format...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for details). Thanks.